# Two languages such that $L_1 \cup L_2 \leq_m\, L_1 \cap L_2$ and two (other?) such that $L_1 \cap L_2 ≤_m\, L_1 \cup L_2$?

Tags: automata

Are there languages $L_1$, $L_2$ such that such that 
$$L_1 \cup L_2\leq_m\, L_1\cap L_2,$$ 
and two other languages such that 
$$L_1 \cap L_2 \leq_m\, L_1 \cup L_2?$$ 
And if so, what are they? How can i go about finding these?

Comment: what is the $m$? I think the http://cs.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for your question

Comment: @Noone the m is for mapping reductions, thanks ill ask there.

Comment: $L_1=L_2=\emptyset$ should work, right?

Comment: Or any $L_1=L_2$ for that matter

Comment: My bad, it should be $$L_1 \cup L_2\leq_m\, L_1\cap L_2,$$ not $$L_1 \cup L_2\leq_m\, L_2\cap L_2,$$ but i like your solution, any solution for the edited one?

Comment: $L_1 = L_2$ is a solution to both the current problems (for any language $L_1$).

Comment: Actually you must look for a computable function $f$, such that $\forall w \in L_1 \cup L_2 \Leftrightarrow f(w) \in L_1 \cap L_2$, not for two languages. Have you ever tried to design any decidable Turing Machine to do this?